# Facebook comments for pictures do not work

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fancybox

I have a picture gallery and I use fancybox to display pictures, and navigate between pictures. Beneath the pictures I integrated the facebook comments plugin to be able to add specific comments for every picture in part.
My problem is that the comments added by people for a specific picture do not appear. However if I add a comment it does show up, but these are only my comments and they appear only if I'm logged in to facebook. Does anybody have some idea what can I do wrong?

The url for the facncybox gallery is: http://www.bass.hr/photogallery.php?album=17
For the facebook comments integration I use the code generated from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ .

Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=196368707123454";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="fancybox_container" style="display:none;">
    <?php
    foreach ($Imgs as $key => $i) {
    ?>
            <div id="inline_<?php echo $key;?>" style="width:500px;">
                <img id="fancyboxContentImage" src="<?php echo $target.$i['filename']; ?>" />
                <div style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <fb:comments href="http://www.bass.hr/<?php echo $target.$i['filename'];?>" num_posts="2" width="450"></fb:comments>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="grouped_elements" href="#inline_<?php echo $key;?>" rel="group" ></a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){
    $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({
        openEffect   : 'fade',
        closeEffect  : 'fade',
        nextEffect   : 'fade',
        prevEffect   : 'fade',
        mouseWheel   : 'true',
        width        :  520,
        height       :  400,
        autoSize     : 'true',
        fitToView    : 'true',
        type         : 'inline',
        scrolling    : 'yes',
        padding      : 10,
        afterShow    :function() {
            var referenceHeight = $('div.fancybox-inner div img').height()+15;
            $('.fancybox-prev, .fancybox-next').css('height', referenceHeight+'px');
        }
    });
    $("#fancybox_container a.grouped_elements:first").click();
});
</script>
```

**Update1:**

I also tried to load the facebook JavaScript SDK asynchronously like described in facebook developers JavaScript SDK reference, but just the same result.

**Update2:**

I also checked the url of my images by inspecting with firebug. If I copy that url and give it as a parameter to the graph api, then the comments are there in the array returned (see comments below for the url that I tried via graph api)

**Update3:**

I created a sepparate test page containing only the image and the facebook comments plugin under it. After that I passed the url to the debugger, so it flushes the cache, but no result.
Here is the url with only the image+plugin: 
bass.hr/photodisplay.php?photo=pic_1293187827.jpg

Any ideas, not necessarily solutions would be much apreciated also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XFBML tags are only parsed on Facebook JS-SDK initialization by default (once DOM is ready). And hidden content is probably skipped. You need to call [`FB.XFBML.parse`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) once you want to render XFBML tags to page

You can do it for every tag on page or in specified node only by passing it as argument to `FB.XFBML.parse` method

**Update:**
Looks like it not really directly related to XFBML rendering but to some character in one of filenames passed to `onload` function which prevents FB.XFBML for loading on page (and this is why any XFMBL tags not rendered at all), wired it happens only on Chrome/Chromium but not of Safari (tested both).

```
<body class="background_main" style="background-image: url(../Images/blackjack3.jpg);" onload="MM_preloadImages('Images/home2.png','Images/o
nama2.png','Images/photogallery2.png','Images/forum2.png','Images/news2.png','Images/kontakt2.png')">
```

This is the error I'm see in Chromium (for some reason the real error can be seen only sometimes in correct place and most times attributed to Facebook's all.js)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (photogallery.php:66)

**Update 2:**

If comments other users posted isn't displayed (or displayed for comment posted only) it may be some reasons:

- Moderation is enabled for comments
- Comments posted as testing users
- For some users marked as spammers (controlled by Facebook) comments isn't displayed
- Facebook bug (which is possible but probably isn't a case)

**Update 3:**

This is probably bug, it may be tracked on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/117814361658299

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I don't think that this is a XFBML tag parsing problem, because I also tried to use the HTML5 version of the code generated at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ and produces the same result. Putting the Facebook JS-SDK initialization on document ready and removing the display none from the div also don't help. I also Tried to call FB.XFBML.parse on all elements on the page, however no luck. The stange thing is that if you open it in google chrome, the facebook comments plugin does not even show up. (In Firefox and IE it does.)

Comment: Corrected issue with chrome, now it appears on Chrome also but the facebook comments still not work it only shows my comments and only when i'm logged in. What else can this be?

Comment: Did you have moderation enabled for `Comments Social Plugin`? Check this in comments moderation tool http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Comment: No I don't have moderation enabled for now. Also the link doesn't seem to work for http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Comment: Moderation tool isn't working for you because of missing fb:app_id/fb:admins meta tags see Moderation Tools section on [Comments Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

Comment: The interseting thing is that if I use the link from the graph api https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.bass.hr/cont/pic_1293187827.jpg for a picture it returns the correct result in the array, so the comments entered before are there. But on the site they do not show up (http://www.bass.hr/photogallery.php?album=76)

Comment: Now I inserted the moderation tool for my app in the head
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{196368707123454}"/>
but no change with or without moderation tool.

Comment: Passing url for your page to [Graph Debuger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will remove the cache for it and re-parse this tags.

Comment: Passed the url for the picture to the graph debugger. Is there anything else that worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out.. it seems that facebook does not let new created users to post comments immediately. If anyone runs into this again check this also.